# not able to run pip in python3 venv (OS : Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS)

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-venv, ubuntu-22.04, pyvenv

I created python virtual env using below command

```
python3 -m venv env
```

But I am not able to run pip inside it to install dependencies, can someone please help,
though I can see pip present inside bin

```
(env) u@u-Lenovo-ideapad-520-15IKB:~/Documents/github/CarPartsDetectionChallenge_v3p/env/bin$ ls -lart
    total 44
    drwxrwxr-x 5 s s 4096 Jan 11 08:49 ..
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 s s    7 Jan 11 08:49 python3.10 -> python3
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 s s   16 Jan 11 08:49 python3 -> /usr/bin/python3
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 s s    7 Jan 11 08:49 python -> python3
    -rwxrwxr-x 1 s s  284 Jan 11 08:50 pip3.10
    -rwxrwxr-x 1 s s  284 Jan 11 08:50 pip3
    -rwxrwxr-x 1 s s  284 Jan 11 08:50 pip
    -rw-r--r-- 1 s s 9033 Jan 11 08:50 Activate.ps1
    -rw-r--r-- 1 s s 2100 Jan 11 08:50 activate.fish
    -rw-r--r-- 1 s s  958 Jan 11 08:50 activate.csh
    -rw-r--r-- 1 s s 2032 Jan 11 08:50 activate
    drwxrwxr-x 2 s s 4096 Jan 11 08:50 .
    (env) s@s-Lenovo-ideapad-520-15IKB:~/Documents/github/CarPartsDetectionChallenge_v3p/env/bin$ python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
    /home/s/Documents/github/CarPartsDetectionChallenge_v3p/env/bin/python3: No module named pip
    (env) s@s-Lenovo-ideapad-520-15IKB:~/Documents/github/CarPartsDetectionChallenge_v3p/env/bin$ pip install tensorflow
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/s/Documents/github/CarPartsDetectionChallenge_v3p/env/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
        from pip._internal.cli.main import main
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
    (env) s@s-Lenovo-ideapad-520-15IKB:~/Documents/github/CarPartsDetectionChallenge_v3p/env/bin$ python3 --version
    Python 3.7.16
```

Already tried steps(didn't work)
1.

```
u@u-Lenovo-ideapad-520-15IKB:~/Documents/github/CarPartsDetectionChallenge_v3p$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip
[sudo] password for u: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
python3-pip is already the newest version (22.0.2+dfsg-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 165 not upgraded.
(env) u@u-Lenovo-ideapad-520-15IKB:~/Documents/github/CarPartsDetectionChallenge_v3p$ python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
/home/u/Documents/github/CarPartsDetectionChallenge_v3p/env/bin/python3: No module named pip
(env) u@u-Lenovo-ideapad-520-15IKB:~/Documents/github/CarPartsDetectionChallenge_v3p$ python3 -m pip3 install -r requirements.txt
/home/u/Documents/github/CarPartsDetectionChallenge_v3p/env/bin/python3: No module named pip3
(env) u@u-Lenovo-ideapad-520-15IKB:~/Documents/github/CarPartsDetectionChallenge_v3p$ pip3 install -r requirements.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/u/Documents/github/CarPartsDetectionChallenge_v3p/env/bin/pip3", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

2. 

```
(env) u@u-Lenovo-ideapad-520-15IKB:~/Documents/github/CarPartsDetectionChallenge_v3p/env/bin$ sudo apt install python3-pip
python3-pip is already the newest version (22.0.2+dfsg-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 165 not upgraded.
(env) u@u-Lenovo-ideapad-520-15IKB:~/Documents/github/CarPartsDetectionChallenge_v3p/env/bin$ pip3 --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/u/Documents/github/CarPartsDetectionChallenge_v3p/env/bin/pip3", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `python3 -m pip3 install -r requirements.txt`

If pip3 isn't found, it seems you need to install pip/pip3.

Comment: (env) souradeep@souradeep-Lenovo-ideapad-520-15IKB:~/Documents/github/CarPartsDetectionChallenge_v3p$ python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
/home/souradeep/Documents/github/CarPartsDetectionChallenge_v3p/env/bin/python3: No module named pip
(env) souradeep@souradeep-Lenovo-ideapad-520-15IKB:~/Documents/github/CarPartsDetectionChallenge_v3p$ ls
1_Image_Annotation  2_Training  3_Inference  Data  env  get-pip.py  LICENSE  Minimal_Example.py  README.md  requirements.txt  TrainYourOwnYOLO.ipynb  Utils

same issue

Comment: It looks like you still didn't try pip3 instead of pip. Have you ensured you have pip(3) installed after activating your env?

Comment: cd env/bin/
 ls
activate  activate.csh  activate.fish  Activate.ps1  pip  pip3  pip3.10  python  python3  python3.10


pip -version
pip3 --version
op:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/u/Documents/github/CarPartsDetectionChallenge_v3p/env/bin/pip3", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
(env) u@u-Lenovo-ideapad-520-15IKB:~/Documents/github/CarPartsDetectionChallenge_v3p/env/bin$

Comment: i can see the pip and pip3 files but when you try running either gives the same error

Comment: (env) u@u-Lenovo-ideapad-520-15IKB:~/Documents/github/CarPartsDetectionChallenge_v3p/env/bin$ sudo apt install python3-pip
python3-pip is already the newest version (22.0.2+dfsg-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 165 not upgraded.
(env) u@u-Lenovo-ideapad-520-15IKB:~/Documents/github/CarPartsDetectionChallenge_v3p/env/bin$ pip3 --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/u/Documents/github/CarPartsDetectionChallenge_v3p/env/bin/pip3", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'

Answer (score -1):

**Link your python with the pip package manager :**

*After activating the virtual Environment run the below commands.*

**For Windows :**

```bash
python3 -m ensurepip
```

**For Linux :**

```bash
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Comment: u@u-Lenovo-ideapad-520-15IKB:~/Documents/github/CarPartsDetectionChallenge_v3p$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip
[sudo] password for u: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
python3-pip is already the newest version (22.0.2+dfsg-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 165 not upgraded.

still same issue